# Invalid template file magento 2

Tags: magento2

Am getting this strange error when i switched from production to developer mode

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'test.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'test'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'test.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'test'
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1099]
#2 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1103]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:673]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:564]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('test') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:540]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('test') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('test') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:495]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('test', true) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('test', true) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:524]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml() called at [vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\container.phtml:7]
#11 include('E:\xampp\htdocs\...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php:59]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template#000000002b1e3639000000007604f743#, 'E:/xampp/htdocs/...', array()) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php:271]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('E:/xampp/htdocs/...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php:301]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1099]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1103]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:673]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Page.php:251]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002b1e209d000000007604f743#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php:171]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002b1e209d000000007604f743#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002b1e209d000000007604f743#)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002b1e209d000000007604f743#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002b1e209d000000007604f743#), array(array('result-messages', 'result-builtin-c...', 'result-varnish-c...'))) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php:130]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002b1e209d000000007604f743#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php:120]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php:24]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php:261]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000002b1e2330000000007604f743#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

and i dont have any test.phtml file in my app/code dir

Comment: `test.phtml` file you call any xml file ?

Comment: nope anyways it has been fixed now thnkss

Comment: perhaps you can provide an answer so that others might be helped, or delete the question.

Comment: Please post the answer..

Comment: @Pramod Every time someone posts "it has been fixed now" without posting their solution, a puppy dies. 
You Monster.